# Detect if touch stopped on the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

The question is simple but extremely complicated: in `UIResponder` there are 4 methods for handling touches.

```
- touchesEnded:withEvent:event
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

How do I detect if a touch stopped on the screen?

The problem is that I have to detect if something moved under a stationary touch (not cancelled or ended. It just doesn't move) And because it doesn't move, none of these methods gets called.

My idea was this:

I could add the touches to a `NSMutableArray` but then I'd have to update it for any touch move (and that's a lot). Also this creates more problems, I need to detect which of the touches stopped and if any ended. And because I get an `NSSet` from `UIResponder`, I don't have an organized array so... all kinds of problems.

I'm waiting for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it..and also found out something really cool about `UITouch`

what i did: in

```
 – touchesBegan:withEvent:
for(UITouch*touch in touches){
[touchesSet addObject:touch]; } //touchesSet is a set that i store all the touches on the screen
```

in

```
- touchesEnded:withEvent:

for(UITouch*touch in touches){
[touchesSet removeObject:touch]; }
```

in

```
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
[touchesSet removeAllObjects];
```

doing this i have a `NSSet` of all the touches on the screen at any given time, with position and `UITouchPhase`

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends a little upon what you're trying to do (and you don't really describe what business problem or user experience you're going for). But assuming you're just trying to detect when a continuous gesture paused but hadn't been completed:

You could have `touchesMoved` keep track of where and when it was last invoked. E.g. if you have a subclassed gesture recognizer, give it a property of `CGPoint lastLocation` or something like that which you could inquire upon.

You could then setup a NSTimer that would be triggered a certain amount of time later, which would test for your "stopped" condition. E.g. if your NSTimer is called every 0.1 seconds and you're waiting for no change in location for, say 1 second, then that would qualify as a stopped condition.

And if you're looking to see if "something moved under a stationary touch", you could add this to your NSTimer routine.

Comment: i don't see how it would depend on user interaction. I just want to see if the touch stopped..the rest doesn't matter. As for your idea it's exactly what i said..only that i was adding them into an array...and then checked that array...what you suggest is basically to add a NSTimed on top of that. Also..there's the problem that i cant check a touch individually (i.e. i can't tell which is which)..so even if i had a timer i wouldn't be able to determine which stopped...i would just know that some touch stopped...not that the one at x:.. y:... did.

Comment: @skytz I must not understand your question. I thought you were asking how to detect when a user is in the middle of some gesture, but stopped/paused, but I presumed that you didn't want to wait for some future `touchesMoved`, `touchedEnded`, or `touchesCancelled` to detect when the user stopped/paused in the middle of the gesture. If you don't use some NSTimer or something like that, I don't know how you'll ever know that the user stopped the gesture but kept their finger on the screen.